# How can I show notification in Android lock screen?

Tags: android, notifications, push, show, lockscreen

Is it possible to show a push notification in the lock screen like iOS does?
I've seen there are a lot of applications that manage notifications so that they appear this way but my question is: is it possible to do that with my application without using these third apps??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am following this tutorial its almost work but there are alot of issues still remain. I am using Activty instead of Service. Please follow this.

[Android Facebook lock screen notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921241/android-facebook-lock-screen-notification)