# Full-Screen Lock Screen Beacon Based Notification on Android

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

We are wondering whether it would be possible to create an app for Android that prompts a notification on the lock screen in the form of a full screen image? This in turn would be triggered by a beacon.

Brief concept design here: 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I encourage you to read more questions and the help section in order to revise your post.  For example, you should eliminate  the greeting and sign-off (even though they are polite) and inline the image.

Comment: You can not create a notification that shows full screen. Notifications are only intended to show some specific information. And Lock screen is controlled by the system itself,i think.

Comment: You could try something similar to shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921241/android-facebook-lock-screen-notification

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. [Android Facebook lock screen notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921241/android-facebook-lock-screen-notification)

There is a example of how to show a notification on lockscreen. you could adapt the layout to your needs.